# Grant user permission in SharePoint 2016 sites by Powershell?

Tags: powershell, permissions, 2016, claims-based-auth

Since SharePoint 2016 sites are claim based sites so I want a Powershell script which grant user permission to site or in group in SharePoint 2016 sites

please help.

Answer (score 1):

You can use PNP PowerShell to add users to a particular SharePoint Group

```
Add-PnPUserToGroup -LoginName finance@yourdomain.co.uk -Identity 'Team Site Members'
```

More information about Add-PnPUserToGroup [here](https://github.com/SharePoint/PnP-PowerShell/blob/master/Documentation/AddPnPUserToGroup.md) and how to set group permission [here](https://github.com/SharePoint/PnP-PowerShell/blob/master/Documentation/SetPnPGroupPermissions.md)